# I need to make a flip video and add 2 watermarks, my script doesn't work for some reason? ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, watermark, flip

I need to make a flip video and add 2 watermarks, my script doesn't work for some reason (the script just flips the video, but does not apply watermarks).

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i watermark.png -i watermark2.png -filter_complex "hflip;[1:v]scale=iw*0.5:-1[top];[2:v]scale=iw*0.1:-1[top2];[0:v][top]overlay=x=(W-w)/40:y=(H-h)/40[tmp];[tmp][top2]overlay=5:H-h-5" -preset superfast output.mp4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to store the output of `hflip` with a temporary name (like `[v0]`), and use it later as input to the `overlay` filter:

`ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -i watermark.png -i watermark2.png -filter_complex "[0:v]hflip[v0];[1:v]scale=iw*0.5:-1[top];[2:v]scale=iw*0.1:-1[top2];[v0][top]overlay=x=(W-w)/40:y=(H-h)/40[tmp];[tmp][top2]overlay=5:H-h-5" -preset superfast output.mp4`

---

In the original command `hflip;` is mapped to the output video, because it has no output sink.
By default FFmpeg maps the first video without a sink to the output.

- `[0:v]hflip[v0]` - horizontally flip the video of the first input, and store the result in `[v0]`.
- `[v0][top]overlay...` - Overlays `[top]` on top of `[v0]`.

Comment: oh, it's working thanks dude